# How can I get the second mention in a message discord.js v13

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I was making a command, that needs two people to be mentioned, But I do not know how I can do this. I wrote something to check if it works or not, but it didn't work

Code 1:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first();
const user2 = message.mentions.members.second() || message.member;
```

Code 2:

```js
const user = message.mentions.members.first([0]);
const user2 = message.mentions.members.first([1]) || message.member;
```

They did not work. Can someone say how can I get 2 members from mentioning?

**Notes**: I am not getting any errors, I am using discord.js v13 and node.js v16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const user = message.mentions.members.first(); // For your first mention
const user1 = message.mentions.members.first(2)[1]; // For your second mention
```

Same with ID's

```
const user = message.mentions.members.first() || await message.guild.member.cache.get(args[0]) || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[0]) // First mention
const user = message.mentions.members.first(2)[1] || await message.guild.member.cache.get(args[1]) || await message.guild.members.fetch(args[1]) // First mention
```

*edit:*

You can also do 3 mentions just adjust the `args[]` for ex:

```
message.mentions.members.first() // First Mention
message.mentions.members.first(2)[1] // Second Mention
message.mentions.members.first(3)[-1] // Third Mention
```

If the third mention didn't worked. Just adjust it to `(3)[2]`